# Mockito: Wanted but not invoked

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a following test method:

```
MyClass myClass= Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);
Mockito.when(myClass.methodUsedInMethodBeingTested(Matchers.any(MyTypeParam.class))).thenReturn(Collections.<X, Y> emptyMap());

assertNull(myClass.methodToTest(myObject));
Mockito.verify(myClass).methodUsedInMethodBeingTested(Matchers.any(MyTypeParam.class));
```

The `methodUsedInMethodBeingTested` is a method that I want to mock and return an empty map. But I am getting the failure message saying

> Wanted but not invoked myClass.methodUsedInMethodBeingTested()

.

```
MyClass
{
   public XYZ methodToTest()
   {
    ....
    ....
    Map<X,Y> mp = methodUsedInMethodBeingTested(myTypeParam);
    .....
   }

   public Map<X,Y> methodUsedInMethodBeingTested(MyTypeParam myTypeParam)
   {
    .....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what a mock is. When you're doing

```
MyClass myClass = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);
// ...
assertNull(myClass.methodToTest(myObject));
```

You're not actually invoking `methodToTest` on your real object. You're invoking `methodToTest` on the mock, which by default, does nothing and return `null`, unless it was stubbed. Quoting from [Mockito docs](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2):

> By default, for all methods that return value, mock returns null, an empty collection or appropriate primitive/primitive wrapper value (e.g: 0, false, ... for int/Integer, boolean/Boolean, ...).

This explains your subsequent error: the method was really not invoked on the mock.

---

It seems what you want here is a [`spy`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) instead:

> You can create spies of real objects. When you use the spy then the **real** methods are called (unless a method was stubbed).

A note of warning though: since it is the real methods that are getting called, you should not use `Mockito.when` but prefer `Mockito.doReturn(...).when`, otherwise the method will be called once for real. If you consider the expression:

```
Mockito.when(myClass.methodUsedInMethodBeingTested(Matchers.any(MyTypeParam.class))).thenReturn(Collections.<X, Y> emptyMap());
             ^-----------------------------------^
                 this will be invoked by Java
```

the argument of the method `when` must be evaluated, but this means the method `methodUsedInMethodBeingTested` will be invoked. And since we have a spy, it is the real method that will be invoked. So, instead, use:

```
MyClass spy = Mockito.spy(new MyClass());
Mockito.doReturn(Collections.<X, Y> emptyMap()).when(spy).methodUsedInMethodBeingTested(Matchers.any(MyTypeParam.class));
assertNull(spy.methodToTest(myObject));
Mockito.verify(spy).methodUsedInMethodBeingTested(Matchers.any(MyTypeParam.class));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have two doubts: 1. I am not able to do this MyClass spy = Mockito.spy(MyClass.class); as it says Type mIsmatch cannot convert from Class<MyClass> to MyClass. 2. Can you please explain this better "A note of warning though: since it is the real methods that are getting called, you should not use Mockito.when but prefer Mockito.doReturn(...).when, otherwise the method will be called once for real:"

Comment: @Vwin I've edited. I used a new method that must not be present on your version of Mockito. For your second concern, I also clarified.

Comment: That is perfect. It worked. Thanks @RomanVottner. Thanks Tunaki, you are awesome :) and the explaination made a lot more sense.

Answer (score 3):

You are invoking the `methodToTest` on the mock instance. Because you have not configured it otherwise, that just returns null, it doesn't try to invoke any of the actual method's implementation.