# Mockito exception: Missing method invocation while trying to test an if conditon

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, junit, mockito

I am trying to test for an if condition using when(),thenReturn(), but when I run my test case it gives me missing method invocation even though I have mocked the class where the method is implemented.

this is the if condition I am trying to mock

```
     if(request.getProcessType() == IPRequest.IPREQUEST_TYPE_TOMO_RECON)//IPREQUEST_TYPE_TOMO_RECON=9, this is the condition I am trying to test    
      {
        params.setTubeAngle(accessor); //I am verifying if these methods are invoked
        params.setTomoFocalSpot(accessor);
      }
```

This is how I am checking for the if condition

```
when(request.getProcessType()).thenReturn(IPRequest.IPREQUEST_TYPE_TOMO_RECON);
        Mockito.verify(ipImgParam,Mockito.times(3)).setTubeAngle(Mockito.any(AttributeExtractor.class));
```

I have already mocked "request" using @Mock annotation but still getting the below exception.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
3. the parent of the mocked class is not public.
   It is a limitation of the mock engine.

    at  common.systemreprocessingservice.test.ImageParamsBuilderTest.testbuildProcessingInfoIf(ImageParamsBuilderTest.java:134)
```

I am not sure what I am doing doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

I cannot write a comment, that's why asking here. What kind of object is "request"? If it is an object of a final class, then you'll need PowerMockito for mocking that.

Also, after using @Mock annotation, did you call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(testClass.class)` method before running the test case?

The following link tells different ways in which you can mock your objects.
https://blog.frankel.ch/initializing-your-mockito-mocks/#gsc.tab=0

Comment: "request" is an object of a public class which I have mocked using @Mock. if I call MockitoAnnotations.initMocks() I get Null pointer exceptions so I have ignored that.

Comment: I think there is some problem that your mocks are not getting injected in the class. Did you try mocking it without annotation? By using `Request request = mock(Request.class)` . 
PS - If non-annotated mocking also doesn't work, then you should try to resolve that NullPointerException first.

Comment: yes I tried mocking it without the annotation as well, but it did not work, instead I got an exception like `Wanted but not invoked:
iPImgParams.setTubeAngle(<any>);
-> at common.systemreprocessingservice.test.ImageParamsBuilderTest.testbuildProcessingInfoIf(ImageParamsBuilderTest.java:137)

However, there were other interactions with this mock:
-> at common.systemreprocessingservice.ImageParamsBuilder.buildProcessingInfo(ImageParamsBuilder.java:34)`

Comment: How are you passing this request object in your test case? I mean, how are you making sure that the method getProcessType() will be called on this mocked object only and not some other object which is created in your class under test?

Comment: You can refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511329/mockito-wanted-but-not-invoked

Comment: I have called other methods using the same object and it worked. Only when I pass it inside `when(request.getProcessType()).thenReturn(int);` its giving me missing method invocation

Comment: so i think that now you're able to create the mock, because the above exception means that the method on the mocked object was never called. 
Now, since the problem is coming only with getProcessType() method, then there could be two things: 1. It is actually not getting called. 2. The request object is getting updated with a new value by some other method, before it calls getProcessType() method.

Please confirm if my understanding is correct about successful mocking above.

Comment: I made the change that was suggested in the link you specified. But now I am getting "wanted but not invoked" the same exception I have posted in my previous comment.

Comment: I have posted another comment. Please check if that is the case. You might have to debug your code for that.

Comment: The request object is not holding any value. I am only using it to call the methods that belong to that class. The exception says "a method call on a Mock". I have done the same but still getting this exception.

Comment: I understand that the request object holds a mock value. So my doubt is that if you're injecting this request object in your class, and then if inside that class, someone else updates the value of request object like `request = something` , then it won't be a mock object anymore. Sorry if it is confusing.

Comment: The value of request object is not getting updated as far as I think .

Comment: Is it possible to share the full code? It will be more helpful in solving this problem.

Comment: I have shared my entire test case above. You can have a look.

Comment: i saw that you've edited your question. Lemme check it once again. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I can see that you're calling the method `imageParamsBuilder.buildProcessingInfo(request, info)` before setting the when condition - `when(request.getProcessType()).thenReturn(IPRequest.IPREQUEST_TYPE_TOMO_RECON)`
 Could you please put this when condition before invoking buildProcessingInfo() method and check? I think this should solve the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting the same exception.

Comment: You have given the verification condition as `Mockito.times(3)`. Are you sure your test case calls those methods exactly 3 times?

Comment: yes because The method that I am testing has a for loop that runs 3 times i.e based on the number of elements in the array "sourceimages" and this if condition that I am trying to test is within the for loop.

Comment: Okay, got it. So one more thing that I can see is that `request.getSourceImages();` is called. But request is a mock object. So can you please confirm if this method call is actually returning what you're adding here `request.addSourceImage(image);` in your test class?

Comment: yes `request.getSourceImages()` does return what I add using `request.addSourceImage(image)` .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136366/discussion-between-blu3-and-hushie).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>    imageParamsBuilder.buildProcessingInfo(request, info);
>     Mockito.verify(ipImgParam, Mockito.times(3)).fillYourSelf(Mockito.any(AttributeExtractor.class));
>    when(request.getProcessType()).thenReturn(IPRequest.IPREQUEST_TYPE_TOMO_RECON);
>     Mockito.verify(ipImgParam,Mockito.times(3)).setTubeAngle(Mockito.any(AttributeExtractor.class));
> ```

The third line here is "too late". You must configure the mock *before* you call the CuT.

---

> It still doesnt solve my problem
>
> ```
> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
> when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
> ```
>
> in Test:
>
> ```
> when(TagAccessorFactory.getInstance()).thenReturn(tagAccessorFactoryMock);
> ```

You can't mock static methods this way, you have to use *PowerMockito*s `when()`  method.

But (once more) I consider the use of *PowerMockito* as a surrender to bad design. You should not use static access to get dependencies but pass them in into your class using DI (either manually or preferable using a DI framework).

---

> when I call the
>
> ```
> when(request.getProcessType()).thenReturn(IPRequest.IPREQUES‌​‌​T_TYPE_TOMO_RECON)‌​;
> ```
>
> before the method call I am getting exception like this
>
> ```
> Wanted but not invoked:"
> ```

you try to test both execution path with the same test method.

You should have separate test methods

Comment: TagAccessorFactory is a singleton class therefore I have to use PowerMockitos

Comment: @hushie *"TagAccessorFactory is a singleton class"* is this your code (or your companies at least)?

Comment: its my code. But the issue is not because of that. when I call the `when(request.getProcessType()).thenReturn(IPRequest.IPREQUEST_TYPE_TOMO_RECON);` before the method call I am getting exception like this `Wanted but not invoked: iPImgParams.setTubeAngle(<any>); -> at common.systemreprocessingservice.test.ImageParamsBuilderTest‌​.testbuildProcessing‌​InfoIf(ImageParamsBu‌​ilderTest.java:137) However, there were other interactions with this mock: -> at common.systemreprocessingservice.ImageParamsBuilder.buildPro‌​cessingInfo(ImagePar‌​amsBuilder.java:34)`